# How to use Espresso UI Testing for React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, ui-testing, android-espresso, fastlane

I'm trying to make some UI Testing with Espresso on my React Native Android application to use Screengrab by Fastlane.

I have followed [this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-android.html) to integrate React Native in an existing app to be able to write a test. But when I started writing my UI Test I was unable to find what to write and how to target a component and perform a click on it for example.

I found  [this](http://testdroid.com/tech/testing-react-native-apps-on-android-and-ios)  post where someone give an example on how to write Espresso Test for React Native but it doesn't work for me ... None of my component have resource-id set so I don't know how to perform some action on my application.

If someone could help me to write a UI Test with Espresso on a React Native app or give me another solution to take automated screenshot of my Android application that'll be awesome.

If you have any question let me know.

Answer (score 16):

## Espresso

Currently there is no way to set resource-id with react-native, so, to make complex actions you need to write some code (like wait for elements), other things seems work quite good via android studio 'record espresso test' button.

1. use prop `accessibilityLabel` as id for elements (eg. "elementId")
2. use `onView(allOf(withContentDescription("elementId"), isDisplayed()))` to get element
3. peform actions on that element (like `element.perform(click())`)

Here you can find full test https://gist.github.com/cybergrind/0a2ad855352a5cd47cb5fb6a486c5eaa

## Appium

If you just want to perform actions and capture screenshots, you can do this with appium:

1. use prop `accessibilityLabel` as id for elements
2. in web driver use waitForElementByAccessibilityId
3. capture screenshots with saveScreenshot('out.png') -> this will create 'out.png' file in directory where you've run tests

In appium you finally will have something like (js example):

```
driver.waitForElementByAccessibilityId('searchInputAcc', 5000)
      .type('bold\n')
      .sleep(5000)
      .saveScreenshot('out.png')
```

## iOS vs Android accessibilityLabels

It seems that for Android you're free to use `accessibiltyLabel` on any element (like Text, View and so on), but iOS won't set accessibility on all elements like Adnroid.

If you set label on `Text` it won't be equal your label

```
<Text accessibilityLabel="my_text">content</Text>
```

will give you label equal `content` on iOS, so basically you can just set `accessible` attribute on your text nodes for this platform

```
<Text accessible>content</Text>
```

Same thing for `View` - iOS will ignore your labels.

So far, not much elements on iOS will work with your custom accessibility labels.

Below is a list of elements that you can use to test application for crossplatform react-native tests

You can use:

- `TouchableHighlight` - will work same on iOS and Android, you can just set accessibilityLabel
- `Text` - accessibilityLabel should be same as inner test + you have to set accessible attribute

Won't work (for both platforms altogether):

- `View`

*P.S. we haven't tested all possible elements yet, so add your results for other elements or wait for our results*

## Debugging

You can get source of root element, print and read it as xml for debugging purposes (for webdriver.io:  http://webdriver.io/api/property/getSource.html)

Answer (score 5):

I have a PR against react-native to add proper support for `resource-id`.   Check it out and up-vote please: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/9942

Once that's merged in `testID` will add `resource-id` so long as the Id is defined in `res/values/ids.xml`.

Comment: I am following your PR's and conversation but just would like to know if that PR is merged with the react? In some conversations I could see that it is turned down.

Answer (score 2):

Currently if you set testID in your react layer that will get translated into a tag in android.

Then with Espresso you can use the provided ViewMatcher `withTagValue`
[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#withTagValue(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Cjava.lang.Object%3E))

Then all you have to do to find a view is

```
onView(withTagValue(is((Object) tagValue))).perform(click());
```