# Recording Espresso tests with React Native

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I'm creating an React Native application and I want to test it with Espresso.

When I click "Record Espresso Test", I get the following error:

> No suitable Android Application configuration found
>
> Please create an Android Application configuration with a valid module and Default or Specified launch activity.

Also, I created a test manually, but the "Run" button is not available for the test.

I found this answer: [How to use Espresso UI Testing for React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167107/how-to-use-espresso-ui-testing-for-react-native)
and set the `accessibilityLabel` for my resources, but that does not seem to have any effect.

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3 for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

If you import the `android` folder from the React Native project into Android Studio, it will behave as a regular Android project, so you will be able to record Espresso tests the usual way.

Comment: Are you able to actually record all the touches? The only thing being recorded in my app are the navigation clicks, but not the Touchable events, for example.

Comment: @AshleyCoolman I actually stopped trying but RN evolved quite a lot, also now when you deploy an app to Android it actually uses Firebase device farm to try out 10 devices for free. I ended up using Appium which is slow but does the work. I lacks a few things but for my use case is fine. It also takes a long time in cloud services like AWS Device Farm. 10 minutes locally vs one hour in AWS.