# The script for Firebase test lab Robo test

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I have a flutter project and I want to try Robo test for it. I don't quite understand how to write a specific script, I tried to do so, but then a matrix for testing is not created (everything is OK without it), I loaded it in the form of json:

```
{
"scenarioLabels": ["loginScenario"],
"actions": [
  {
    "action": "click",
    "description": "Click the 'Enter' button",
    "widget": {
      "text": "Enter",
      "type": "Button",
      "timeout": 10000
    }
  },
  {
    "action": "typeText",
    "description": "Type in phone number",
    "widget": {
      "text": "Input phone number",
      "type": "EditText",
      "timeout": 10000
    },
    "text": <phone number test accounts>
  }
  ....
]}
```

I also suggested cutting it through Android Studio, but I don't understand what these tools are in the - Firebase - Test lab: "Please create an Android Application or Blaze Command Run configuration with a valid module and Default or Specified launch activity."

Comment: Do you have any steps for reproduction of this issue?

`Please create an Android Application or Blaze Command Run configuration with a valid module and Default or Specified launch activity.` looks to be coming from Android Studio. Perhaps this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42295021/2624119 might help? 
If you are seeing/will see errors from Firebase Test Lab itself, please share a "matrix ID" so the team can investigate. A matrix ID is a string that looks like this: `matrix-2bu5fy5f3on63`

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to use Roboscripts with Flutter? I managed basic click actions but still cannot fill in text like user login and password... Would appreciate some pointers.